# Getting filename (or deleting file) using file handle

Tags: php, file

Is there a possibility to obtain filename from file handle? Or how can I delete file having only a handle?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Would love to have a solution though.

Comment: I would love to have at least possibility to cast resource to filename.

Comment: It's kinda weird 'cause you need the filename in order to set the handler, right?

Comment: @ts: With the flick of a magic wand, poof!

Comment: @Alfabravo: Not all PHP functions make handles using filenames.

Comment: @BoltClock Never said so. But IN THIS CASE, setting a file handler requires the filename. Right?

Comment: if you use tmpfile() it returns a file handle - but you have no idea what the filename is!!!

Comment: isn't it ridiculous how PHP doesn't provide this obvious basic functionality, and you have to do multiline shennanigans?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

There is [stream_get_meta_data](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php). It works for a stream that you get from [tmpfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php). If you call it on a regular file pointer then you might only get the basename.

```
$meta_data = stream_get_meta_data($stream_or_file_pointer);
$filename = $meta_data["uri"];
echo $filename;
```

Example for tmpfile():

```
"/private/var/folders/v3/n54x13jx5v7610fw9dm0wcxm0000gn/T/phpCJvevP"
```

Example for fopen("somefile", "r"):

```
"test"
```

Comment: This works! I don't know how this didn't came up as the accepted answer, and everyone here say that this is impossible. Works on Windows too.

Comment: Thanks for this, seems like such a simple thing, but turns out to be such a headache ... You can/should also use `realpath` to get the full filepath.

Comment: Thank you Wayne Weibel. `realpath` is what I was looking for. I came to this page looking for a way to determine the filename in the same case as it exists in the filesystem.

Answer (score 8):

<s>Nyes. Afaik there is no function in PHP to that directly. But</s> on Linux, you can do

```
$fp = fopen('somefile', 'r');
$stat = fstat($fp);
$inode = $stat['ino'];
system("find -inum $inode", $result);
echo $result;
```

This is untested so it might need tweaking.

**EDIT** Apparently, there *is* a [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690726/208809).

Comment: This is the only way I can think of doing it, save for performing the `find` within PHP, though that would probably be slower.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you will need to create a wrapper that stores the file name. A file handle has no context of the filename it was created from.

Comment: For an example of this approach, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30985867/2908724).

Answer (score -4):

A clean method to use temporary file:

```
<?
$tmp=array_search('uri', @array_flip(stream_get_meta_data($GLOBALS[mt_rand()]=tmpfile())));
file_put_contents($tmp, 'hello');
echo file_get_contents($tmp);
?>
```

without need to fclose the tmp file, it will be deleted while the php ends.

Comment: You seriously call this a "clean method" ?