# PHP: How to check the access mode of already opened file handler?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a PHP stream resource is readable or writable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294305/how-to-check-if-a-php-stream-resource-is-readable-or-writable)

Does PHP provide any function to check the access mode of file handle?
Suppose I opened a file in read only mode.

```
 $file_handle = fopen('putty.log','r');
```

Can I check a particular handle's access mode in code?

Comment: What do you need this for? What's the [overall goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)?

Comment: @outis frankly, no specific goal for now. one use may be 'restrict access to write mode handlers'. thanks for editing question :)

Comment: Here's an earlier post with a solution and detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294305/how-to-check-if-a-php-stream-resource-is-readable-or-writable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution to find the mode:

Use function [stream_get_meta_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php):

```
$file_handle = fopen('putty.log','r');
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($file_handle);
echo $metadata['mode'];
```

For more on the array returned read the manual.