# PHP - How to test if stream created by stream_socket_client is open and writeable?

Tags: php

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294305/how-to-check-if-a-php-stream-resource-is-readable-or-writable) but in my case I am wanting to know if the stream returned by `stream_socket_client` is open and writeable.

I know that `stream_socket_client` will return `FALSE` if the stream could not be opened, but I am needing to detect later on if the stream has been closed by the server (or closed due to some network error, for example).

At the moment I'm just doing...

```
$fp = stream_socket_client($apns_url, $error_code, $error_string, $timeout_secs, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
//looping through / sending data
if (!fp) {
    //re-open connection
}
```

...but I'm not sure if my `if (!fp) {...}` check is sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `stream_get_meta_data` for checking if stream is writable.

```
 $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

 if(is_writable($meta['uri'])) { 
 // stream is writable
 }
```

Use `feof` for checking if stream is open.

- `Returns TRUE if the file pointer is at EOF or an error occurs
  (including socket timeout);`

Comment: Hey, I am using PHP7.4.3 Win10 x64 And `stream_get_meta_data` doesn't contain uri index. What can be the problem??

Comment: @aXuser264 can you open a question on that posting more code? You should get output that would contain `uri` index also. Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

Try checking for end of file instead of checking if it is false

```
while (!feof($fp)) {...}
```