# How to get a temporary file path?

Tags: php, temporary-files

I know you can create a temporary file with tmpfile and than write to it, and close it when it is not needed anymore. But the problem I have is that I need the absolute path to the file like this:

```
"/var/www/html/lolo/myfile.xml"
```

Can I somehow get the path, even with some other function or trick?

#### EDIT:

I want to be able to download the file from the database, but without

```
$fh = fopen("/var/www/html/myfile.xml", 'w') or die("no no");
fwrite($fh, $fileData);
fclose($fh);
```

because if I do it like this, there is a chance of overlapping, if more people try to download the same file at exactly the same time. Or am I wrong?

#### EDIT2:

Maybe I can just generate unique(uniqID) filenames like that, and than delete them. Or can this be too consuming for the server if many people are downloading?

Comment: do you have access to your server? how is it hosted?

Comment: yes, i have full access.

Comment: then cant you find the path through a ftp client or with ssh?  is this path constantly changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For newer (not very new lol) versions of PHP (requires php 5.2.1 or higher) @whik's answer is better suited:

```
<?php 
// Create a temp file in the temporary 
// files directory using sys_get_temp_dir()
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'MyFileName');
echo $temp_file;
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to: /var/tmp/MyFileNameX322.tmp

#### old answer

Just in case someone encounters exactly the same problem. I ended up doing

```
$fh = fopen($filepath, 'w') or die("Can't open file $name for writing temporary stuff.");
fwrite($fh, $fileData);
fclose($fh);
```

and

```
unlink($filepath);
```

at the end when file is not needed anymore.

Before that, I generated filename like that:

```
$r = rand();        
$filepath = "/var/www/html/someDirectory/$name.$r.xml";
```

Answer (score 48):

There are many ways you can achieve this, here is one

```
<?php 
// Create a temp file in the temporary 
// files directory using sys_get_temp_dir()
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'MyFileName');
echo $temp_file;
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:
/var/tmp/MyFileNameX322.tmp

Comment: Should the temporary file stay if i did not unlink it at the end?

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to stay anyway

Comment: If you need your file to persist, this approach is unlikely to help. Please give more details of what you are trying to do, i can help!

Comment: Keep in mind that: sys_get_temp_dir() requires php 5.2.1 or higher

Comment: If you just want a resource (the same thing you get with fopen()) you can use tmpfile(). However, legrandviking's method is useful if you actually need a file with a path.

Answer (score 10):

> I know you can create a temporary file with tmpfile

That is a good start, something like this will do:

```
$fileHandleResource = tmpfile();
```

> Can I somehow get the path, even with some other function or trick?

Yes:

```
$metaData = stream_get_meta_data($fileHandleResource);
$filepath = $metaData['uri'];
```

This approach has the benefit of leaving it up to PHP to pick a good place and name for this temporary file, which could end up being a good thing or a bad thing depending on your needs. But it is the simplest way to do this if you don't yet have a specific reason to pick your own directory and filename.

References:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php

[Getting filename (or deleting file) using file handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144583/getting-filename-or-deleting-file-using-file-handle)

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the [directory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php). I guess after that you are on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I just generated a temporary file, deleted it, and created a folder with the same name

```
$tempFolder = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'MyFileName');
unlink($tempFolder);
mkdir($tempFolder);
```