# Can I CURL POST using file handles created with PHP tmpfile?

Tags: php, curl, temporary-files

Assuming I have an array of file handles created using PHP's tmpfile() function, can I send the files as attachments using PHP curl?

Ordinarily, I'd make an associative array in the form $postdata[fieldname] = '@path_to_file', but since I can't determine the path of the tmpfile (I only have the handle), I'm at a loss.

Motivation: I don't want to have to separately purge the contents of these tmpfiles from disk. I feel the tmpfile behavior suits this purpose but the curl component is complicating things.

*Post-Answer Consideration: Jay's answer clears this up, but I came across a deal-breaker shortcoming of tmpfile: the "clean-up" behavior is skipped in the event of a FATAL or abrupt termination of the process, so manual purging would be necessary as a fail-safe. I don't think there's any way to circumvent the process of going through the filesystem and ensuring everything is cleaned up, tmpfile or not.*

Comment: In the documentation of `tmpfile()` you can see two functions allowing you to retrieve the full path : `tempnam()` and sys_get_temp_dir()`

Comment: right, but my impression is that only tmpfile cleans itself up at the conclusion of the script or on fclose.

Comment: You are right about this assumption yes so I understand why it's easier for you to use `tmpfile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php

You can do the following:

```
$t = tmpfile();
$a = stream_get_meta_data($t);

$filename = $a['uri'];
```

This question is similar to: [Getting filename (or deleting file) using file handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144583/getting-filename-or-deleting-file-using-file-handle)

Comment: awesome! thank you Jay, and you're right, the question you linked would have saved me this question.