# Get filesystem path from a PHP streamwrapper?

Tags: php

If I have a file in a php streamwrapper, such as `"media://icon.png"` how can I get it to tell me the filesystem path of that file, assuming it's on a filesystem?

I looked on the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) but didn't see a method to return the streamwrapper path.

Comment: Who says it has to use a file behind the scene? That's the whole purpose of stream wrappers: to use the well-known file manipulation functions with data streams that are not necessarily tied to the file system.

Comment: In this case, I want to construct a `src` path for an html `img` tag. Where I'm using it, I'm pretty certain it's a file, and I can always use something like `is_file()` to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StreamWrapper class represents generic streams. Because not all streams are backed by the notion of a filesystem, there isn't a generic method for this.

[If the `uri` property from `stream_get_meta_data` isn't working for your implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690726/2908724), you can record the information during open time then access it via `stream_get_meta_data`.  Example:

```
class MediaStream {
    public $localpath = null;

    public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path)
    {
        $this->localpath = realpath(preg_replace('+^media://+', '/', $path));

        return fopen($this->localpath, $mode, $options);
    }
}

stream_wrapper_register('media', 'MediaStream');

$fp   = fopen('media://tmp/icon.png', 'r');
$data = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
var_dump(
    $data['wrapper_data']->localpath
);
```

Of course, there's always a brute force approach: after creating your resource, you can call [`fstat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php), which includes the device and inode.  You can then open that device, walk its directory structure, and find that inode.  [See here for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5144755/2908724)